# Track device orientation in background mode

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am developing an iPhone application and tracking the device orientation using the API calls. but I can track the device orientation while the application is in foreground using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];
```

I need to get the notification when my application is in background mode as well.

Please let me know how can I get orientation notification in background mode.

Comment: if is the application needs to be AppStore-safe, the answer is very simple: no way to do it.

Comment: Explain a bit more why you need to do this.

Comment: @Gordon, my application is woking in background to track the user activities . i am reading ASL logs(apple system logs) to track the user activity that would do as well in background mode. So another requirement is to track the orientation in background mode.

Comment: There's a limit to what you can do in the background on iOS5&6 and something like this isn't covered.  If you're doing something else legitimately in the background (e.g. recording audio or reading the location) then you may be able to test the orientation at the same time (or perhaps the accelerometers directly).  You wouldn't get a notification though.

Comment: i have enabled the audio mode in plist and playing the a music in background. but still i am not able to detect the orientation in background.

Comment: You could try polling the device orientation with `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)`

Comment: If your app is a music player, why are you reading ASL logs and “track[ing] user activity”, and why does it matter how the device is oriented?